# repeated Task: changing TextView in a ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView that contain a TextView in every item of the list.

```
<LinearLayout
......>
<i>//other views</i>
.....
<TextView android:id="@+id/frequently_changing" > <i>//updated every 1s</i>

</LinearLayout>
```

How to change textView out of my activity for example a Timer, thread .. without having a security error "only the UI man thread that created the view have the right to change it"

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) for updating Textview from Thread as

```
public void myThread(){
        Thread th=new Thread(){

         @Override
         public void run(){
          try
          {

           while(true)
           {

           Thread.sleep(100L); //SET INTERVAL TO UPDATE TEXTVIEW TEXT
           Your_Current_Activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

            TextView txt= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview); 
            txt.setText(str);  SET TEXT HERE
           });
           }
          }catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
       }
         }
        };
        th.start();
       }
```